# Guideline for Statement of purpose

Tags: phd, united-states, application, statement-of-purpose

In the guidelines for the statement of purpose for a PhD one of them says this: "A self-assessment of any past research experience and analytical skills.". This is my first ever statement of purpose and I'm not really familiar with it, plus I'm not an native English speaker, so I'm not sure I understood it correctly. Do I have to write about what I've done in research, like projects I participated in, the tasks I performed...? And what does analytical skills refer to?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means you should describe the research you have done in the past. Mention the project or projects you have worked on, describe your specific contributions and what your findings were, and why the result is relevant to the field.

Use specific examples and be explicit about what you did e.g. "I performed the G-blob colour calculation, finding that..." or "I wrote a Python code to analyse Q-cell data, which revealed that...". Try to use examples which are linked in some way to the research you would like to be doing in the PhD you are applying to, for example, "My finding that G-blobs are more brightly coloured than Q-cells is in line with the recent results of Prof. Ann Onymous's research group in which they showed that Q-cells are dull in the presence of L-spikes. I envisage a future project in which we could study the  effects of L-spikes on G-blob colour."

It doesn't have to be the next Nobel Prize-winning idea, it just needs to demonstrate that you've thought a bit about the open problems in your field and where your work fits into the big picture.

In my field, analytical skills would probably refer to data analysis and programming skills, but in another field it might be different.

Lastly, send your draft statement around to lots of people to get feedback on it before you submit it, especially if you aren't confident with your English.

Comment: it is limited to 1000 words and there are other guidelines, should I get into many details? i.e. should I explain the type of data analysis (t-test, ANOVA...) I did or describe all the findings? I worked on two research projects and explaining both of them in detail would take a lot of words and I already have more than 1000. And for the analytical skills, is it better to list them after the research paragraph and give examples or do that in the same paragraph and intertwine both?

Comment: @elenaga18 you need to judge how familiar the reader will be with the tests you describe. If everyone in your field knows what an ANOVA is, don't explain it, just say you did it and what you found. As for the analytical skills, that's your choice: there's no one correct way to do things (though a plain list would be more appropriate in a CV). Either way could be good if it's written well or bad if it's written badly. I would show your draft to your Master's supervisor or whoever else is going to write your reference letters asap to get their opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the SoP should be forward looking, not backward. What do you intend to study? The field and, if possible, the subfield. What are your goals for study and thereafter?

For the most part the CV details the past, not the SoP.

However, they are asking you for information about your experience and skills as they enable your goals and will help assure success in attaining them. By "analytical skills" they might mean nothing more than "relevant skills" though in some fields it might mean more, such as lab experience, library research skills, or whatever is most applicable to the field.

But, put the projects and tasks, etc. in the CV and only mention in the SoP them as they support future study.

Note that the SoP is usually considered a quite important part of the application in the US.